# Restrict drag-and-droppable rows in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag and drop rows with in same table using html5, but I would like to restrict the drop area to few rows instead of whole table.

Code :

```
<table id="visibletable" class="dra-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Visible</th>
                            <th>Width</th>
                            <th>Color</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ondrop="dropPart(event)" ondragover="allowDropPart(event)">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="partdesc1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="dragPart(event)">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="partdesc2"  draggable="true" ondragstart="dragPart(event)">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="partdesc3"  draggable="true" ondragstart="dragPart(event)">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="partdesc4"  draggable="true" ondragstart="dragPart(event)">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="partdesc5"  draggable="true" ondragstart="dragPart(event)">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

First 3 rows in the table are not be allowed to drag and draggable rows should not be allowed to drop with in first 3 rows.

Currently I am have applied `ondrop="dropPart(event)"` at the tbody tag so I am able to drop rows any where in the table, Is there a way to restrict drop area?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Refere Below Link For Native HTML5 Drag and Drop

http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-row/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/